# Is there a way to tell my horse to get lost?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

I've got a horse that I'm trying to keep alive for a particular achievement.  Unfortunately, this horse seems a bit suicidal.  Several times he's stepped out in front of my shot during a gunfight and taken a rifle round to the head.  In other instances, he blunders into the wilderness when I stop to hunt, and ends up cougar food.  Still other times he's gotten spooked and jumped into a river and died.

When I'm going to be doing something potentially dangerous to my horse (turning the game on, for example), I'd like to be able to tell him to go away.  I can always call him back with my magic-pocket-dimension-opening whistle if I need to, but there are times when I need to go far afield and walking just isn't going to cut it.  I could bring a "disposable horse" but this achievement is awfully picky and I'd rather stick with just one horse until I get it.

Is there any way to dismiss my horse so that he despawns and is no longer at risk?

Comment: Only advice I can offer: [Keep it away from trains!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWAPkPyIb7I)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to preserve your horse while attempting to complete the "Spurred to Victory" achievement is to hitch your destined horse to a post, and then only use other horses. This is easily done if you are able to use purchased horse deeds.

To the point of dismissing a horse while actively using it, the answer is no. Your options are limited to leaving the horse a good distance away from the action, and then praying a cougar is busy napping or that the horse doesn't see anything shiny at the bottom of a cliff.

Comment: Don't forget the bit about trains! I dunno how many times my horse moseyed onto the tracks when left unsupervised.

Answer (score 0):

If you sneak for a few seconds, your horse will wait. Then you should be able to move normally without the horse charging into "battle".